# Controller not registered after migrating to Angular 1.6.1 Component

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, controller

I am migrating from Angular 1.4.8 to 1.6.1 in preparation of migrating to Angular 2.  I  have been following Joe Eames' pluralsight steps for migrating to the latest version of Angular 1 (1.5+) prior to migrating to Angular 2.   I seem to have done everthing correctly but I am getting the error message,

> [$controller:ctrlreg] The controller with the name 'userLogin' is not
>   registered.

I have checked other Stack Overflow posts. One shows position of the reference to the controller in the scripts file so I moved the reference to the userLogin script up and problem persisted.  I have included my component code and the section of the routing that pertains to userLogin.  Note that I am using ui-router which may be causing the problem but not sure why.  Appreciate any suggestions on what I might be doing wrong.

```
userLogin.js
(function () {
'use strict';
var app = angular.module('app',[]);
angular.module('app').component('userLogin',{
    templateURL: '/account/userLogin.html',
    bindings: {
    },
    controller: function userLogin($http, flIdentity, flNotifier,flAuth, $state, flConstructQueryParameterService) {
        this.identity = flIdentity;
        //Take out both lines after testing - Do not even leave the variables
        this.username = "j.terranova@comcast.net";
        this.password = "joe";
        this.signin = function (username, password) {
            flAuth.authenticateUser(username, password).then(function (success) {
                if (success) {
                    flConstructQueryParameterService.setOwnerId(flIdentity.currentUser._id);
                    flNotifier.notify('You have successfully signed in!');
                    console.log("login - successful signin see if currentUser is defined " + flIdentity.currentUser);
                } else {
                    flNotifier.notify('Username/Password combination incorrect');
                }
            });
            $state.go('home');
        }

        this.signout = function () {
            console.log('Signing User Out ');
            flAuth.logoutUser().then(function () {
                this.username = "";
                this.password = "";
                flNotifier.notify('You have successfully signed out!');
                $state.go('home');
            })
        };

        this.loadReferenceData = function () {
            console.log('Loading Reference Data ');
            $http.post("/loadReferenceData")
                .then(
                    function (response) {
                        // success callback
                    },
                    function (response) {
                        // failure callback
                    }
                );
        };
        this.signUp = function () {
            console.log("login - SignUp function");
            //$modalInstance.close();
            $state.go('signup');
        }
    }
    });
})();

--------------------------------------------------
app.js
        .state('login', {
            url: '/login',
            views: {
                'content-header': {
                    templateUrl: '/app/main/main-header',
                    controller: 'flMainCtrl',
                    caseInsensitiveMatch: true
                },
                'content-banner': {
                    templateUrl: '/app/main/main-carousel',
                    controller: 'flMainCtrl',
                    caseInsensitiveMatch: true
                },
                'content-main': {
                    template: '<user-login></user-login>',
                    //controller: 'login',
                    caseInsensitiveMatch: true
                },
                'content-left': {
                    templateUrl: '/app/main/main-menu-left',
                    controller: 'flMainCtrl',
                    caseInsensitiveMatch: true
                },
                'content-right': {
                    templateUrl: '/app/main/main-menu-right',
                    controller: 'flMainCtrl',
                    caseInsensitiveMatch: true
                },
                'content-footer': {
                    templateUrl: '/app/main/main-footer',
                    controller: 'flMainCtrl',
                    caseInsensitiveMatch: true
                }
            }
        })
```

Comment: Create a [mcve] demo in plunker that reproduces issue

Comment: try changing `controller: function userLogin(` to `controller: function (`.

Comment: The error message was caused by use of the same controller w/ multiple templates.  I have fixed this but am still having a problem.   I am finding the UI-router to be a bit finicky when using components.  My UI Router includes multiple routes and each route 6 views.  Initially I was trying to just change one controller (ie. one route, one view) . This one component/template did not display. I changed all views of the route to components and now no templates display. I am now going to cut back to 2 routes and only use components, no controllers, for all views.  Ideas or similar experiences?

Comment: Not without a demo. Put an example together in plunker

Comment: This is my first plunk in almost 60 years. https://plnkr.co/edit/QsiFehbRkr7AYAYV4yiM?p=preview  .  Luckily someone posted a similar problem today and I was able to leverage that.  My actual situation is a bit more involved than this as I have 6 views for each URL.  Getting this to work will help. I was able to get the original plunk to work but per the documentation I am using, https://ui-router.github.io/guide/ng1/route-to-component, each UI router should be referencing the component and not the template Url.  I am using Angular 1.6.1.  Any help you can provide would be appreciated.

Comment: Per the "Guide: Route to Component" referenced above, I should be using version 1 of the ui-router.  That is probably a problem with the plunk as well.  I have upgraded my code to version 1 of the ui-router but I continue to have a problem even without components.   Getting back to the Plunk, I was able to upgrade to Angular 1.5.5 but I did not see how to upgrade the ui-router in the Plunk.  Anyone know how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found my problem to be similar to one posted subsequent to mine.   I have added an answer to that post and will refer others who have this same problem to refer to Answer 5 of the post, Angular.js UI-Router templates are not loading, [Angular.js UI-Router templates are not loading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41757155/angular-js-ui-router-templates-are-not-loading).

As a note to those migrating to Angular 1.5.x or higher, be sure to upgrade to at least version 1 of the ui-router as I do not believe that earlier version of ui support the component syntax.

I have since added views to the plunk and an enhanced version can be found at: https://plnkr.co/edit/IfqtANj1ocGsZcLIjMUR?p=preview, change to the ui-router as shown below:
// Code goes here

```
(function() {
'use strict';

angular.module('myVin', ['ui.router', 'homeModel', 'about1Model', 'about2Model','contactModel' ])
    .config(function($stateProvider,  $urlRouterProvider) {
        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
        $stateProvider
            .state('home', {
                component: 'home.component',
            })
            .state('about', {
              views: {
                "content-about1": {component: 'about1.component'},
                "content-about2": {component:'about2.component'}
              }
            })
            .state('contact', {
                component: 'contact.component',
            });
    });
})();
```