# Angular.js UI-Router templates are not loading

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm making a simple Angular Website. For Routing I'm using Angular-ui-router. When I click on Home, About the templates are not loading whereas when I click on Contact the template loads perfectly. Can someone please help me where I made a mistake.Here is the link for plunker

```
> https://plnkr.co/edit/8LlDl08JVbQKiD5eWEah?p=preview
```

Comment: edit comment please check it ->remove backslash in your about component

Answer (score 1):

you are using for contact home and about always same module 'homeModel'

```
angular.module('homeModel', [])
```

the contact ist the last one and overwrites it

```
  <script src="home.component.js"></script>
    <script src="about.component.js"></script>
    <script src="contact.component.js"></script>
```

so use unique module for every component

also make sure you add it in your script for example

```
 angular.module('myVin', ['ui.router', 'homeModel', 'contactModel', 'aboutModel'])
```

also remove backslash to get about.html

```
templateUrl: '/about.html',
```

Comment: For Each page do I need to make a new model every time? So, If I had more than 20 pages for each page I need to make a separate model and use?

Comment: You need for every page a controller which holds your message

and you can put all your controllers in your module 'myVin'

check this blog:https://scotch.io/tutorials/angular-routing-using-ui-router

Answer (score 0):

You should be using **templateUrl** property as below code.

Your contact page was working because it is defined as a **component**

```
// Code goes here

(function() {
    'use strict';

    angular.module('myVin', ['ui.router', 'homeModel'])
        .config(function($stateProvider,  $urlRouterProvider) {
            $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
            $stateProvider
                .state('home', {
                    url: '/',
                    templateUrl: 'home.html'
                })
                .state('about', {
                    url: '/about',
                    templateUrl: 'about.html'
                })
                .state('contact', {
                    url: '/contact',
                    template: '<contact></contact>'
                });
        });
})();
```

**[Updated PLUNK](https://plnkr.co/edit/drbjft7gGK0VJXsLUiSW?p=preview)**

Answer (score 0):

In the script.js , you are using `'template'` and wrote `'<home></home>'`, but you have home.html. and you want to use home.html as a template.
You should use  `templateUrl: 'home.html'`   instead   `template:'<home></home>'`

Also change your code for  `template: <about></about>`  &  `template: <contact></contact>`

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    angular.module('myVin', ['ui.router', 'homeModel'])
        .config(function($stateProvider,  $urlRouterProvider) {
            $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
            $stateProvider
                .state('home', {
                    url: '/',
                    template: '<home></home>'
                })
                .state('about', {
                    url: '/about',
                    template: '<about></about>'
                })
                .state('contact', {
                    url: '/contact',
                    template: '<contact></contact>'
                });
        });
})();
```

**see in the snapshot, please do change in red box in your code :**

[image: please do change in red box in your code]

**use this code in script.js and run again your code will run successfully:**

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    angular.module('myVin', ['ui.router', 'homeModel'])
        .config(function($stateProvider,  $urlRouterProvider) {
            $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
            $stateProvider
                .state('home', {
                    url: '/',
                    templateUrl: 'home.html'
                })
                .state('about', {
                    url: '/about',
                    templateUrl: 'about.html'
                })
                .state('contact', {
                    url: '/contact',
                    templateUrl: 'contact.html'
                });
        });
})();
```

**See the snapshot after changing the code:**

[image: See the snapshot after changing the code]

**@Arjun:
Your code is also correct, add some html in your template ( Like, i have done, i wrote  `template: '<h1>Shubham Verma</h1>'` )**

(function() {
        'use strict';

```
    angular.module('myVin', ['ui.router', 'homeModel'])
        .config(function($stateProvider,  $urlRouterProvider) {
            $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
            $stateProvider
                .state('home', {
                    url: '/',
                    template: '<h1>Shubham Verma</h1>'
                })
                .state('about', {
                    url: '/about',
                    templateUrl: 'about.html'
                })
                .state('contact', {
                    url: '/contact',
                    templateUrl: 'contact.html'
                });
        });
})();
```

**Please see the snapshot:**

[image]

Comment: In component, I'm providing as templateUrl and in the config, I gave as a template. So why It does n't work?

Comment: Its aslo working.

I have change the code as your-

                    .state('home', {
                        url: '/',
                        template: '<h1>Shubham Verma</h1>'
                    }
  
Its displaying:  Shubham Verma

Comment: Please see my last updae on the same.
Your code is correct. add some more html like  <h1>Arjun</h1>  template.

Comment: did you got your answer ?

Comment: Yes I got the answer @Shubham Verma

Answer (score 0):

```
You are overwriting your module. 

angular.module('moduleName',[]) 

is use to define a module for using that module further you should use like below

angular.module('moduleName')

Replace your files like given below

replace content of about.component.js with given below code

(function() {
    'use strict';

    angular.module('homeModel')
        .component('about', {
            templateUrl: 'about.html',
            controller: function () {
                var ctrl = this;

                ctrl.mesgs = ['Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo.',
                'Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt. Cras dapibus. Vivamus elementum semper nisi. Aenean vulputate eleifend tellus. Aenean leo ligula, porttitor eu, consequat vitae, eleifend ac, enim. Aliquam lorem ante, dapibus in, viverra quis, feugiat a, tellus', 
                'Phasellus viverra nulla ut metus varius laoreet. Quisque rutrum. Aenean imperdiet. Etiam ultricies nisi vel augue. Curabitur ullamcorper ultricies nisi. Nam eget dui. Etiam rhoncus.'];
            }
        });
})();



And replace code of component.contact.js with given below code


(function() {
    'use strict';

    angular.module('homeModel')
        .component('contact', {
            templateUrl: 'contact.html',
            controller: function () {
                var ctrl = this;

                ctrl.msgs = ['Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo.',
                'Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt. Cras dapibus. Vivamus elementum semper nisi. Aenean vulputate eleifend tellus. Aenean leo ligula, porttitor eu, consequat vitae, eleifend ac, enim. Aliquam lorem ante, dapibus in, viverra quis, feugiat a, tellus', 
                'Phasellus viverra nulla ut metus varius laoreet. Quisque rutrum. Aenean imperdiet. Etiam ultricies nisi vel augue. Curabitur ullamcorper ultricies nisi. Nam eget dui. Etiam rhoncus.'];
            }
        });
})();

It will work fine
```

Answer (score 0):

For those looking to eventually migrate to Angular 2, I had a similar problem.  As an intermediated step in migrating to Angular 2 I have been trying to upgrade to Angular 1.6.1 along with the version of the ui-router that supports components. I copied your plunk, added the external library for version 1 of the ui-router and then made the changes as described in the "Guide: Route to Component", https://ui-router.github.io/guide/ng1/route-to-component .  This included some syntax changes to your components and a call to the component rather than the url and template for each state. See this link for the working plunk, https://plnkr.co/edit/QsiFehbRkr7AYAYV4yiM?p=preview

```
script.js
(function() {
'use strict';

angular.module('myVin', ['ui.router', 'homeModel', 'aboutModel', 'contactModel' ])
    .config(function($stateProvider,  $urlRouterProvider) {
        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
        $stateProvider
            .state('home', {
                component: 'home.component',
            })
            .state('about', {
                component: 'about.component',
            })
            .state('contact', {
                component: 'contact.component',
            });
    });
})();

about.component.js
   (function() {
    'use strict';

angular.module('homeModel', [])
    .component('about', {
        templateUrl: '/about.html',
        controller: function () {
            var ctrl = this;

            ctrl.mesgs = ['Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo.',
            'Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt. Cras dapibus. Vivamus elementum semper nisi. Aenean vulputate eleifend tellus. Aenean leo ligula, porttitor eu, consequat vitae, eleifend ac, enim. Aliquam lorem ante, dapibus in, viverra quis, feugiat a, tellus', 
            'Phasellus viverra nulla ut metus varius laoreet. Quisque rutrum. Aenean imperdiet. Etiam ultricies nisi vel augue. Curabitur ullamcorper ultricies nisi. Nam eget dui. Etiam rhoncus.'];
        }
    });
})();
```